# What is the best practice to run applications having GUI written to KDE (like kdenlive, for example)?

Tags: kde, qt

Here are three scenarios how can I use such applications with KDE specific GUI:

1. Have separate distro for them, Kubuntu, for example.
2. Install KDE plasma desktop in Ubuntu and start KDE session when I need to use kdenlive
3. Install kdenlive in Ubuntu with all dependencies (which includes KDE libs) and start it from Unity.

What is most rational?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, what gives the best performance?, the best integration?..?

Comment: I see two factors: 1. Performance. 2. That the application's GUI looks like it was designed to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have a separate distro only for running some program is definitely a bad Idea
2. Since kdenlive is a kde app, It's interface is integrated to kde environment, So running kde apps from kde is good choice
3. Kde apps can the themed by by GTK themes, So kde apps can have almost native interface of gnome apps in unity